# Jackson serialising including types for nested Collection

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following code

```
@org.junit.Test
public void test1() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

    Map<UUID, String> map = new HashMap<UUID, String>();
    map.put(new UUID(1,2), "value1");
    Set<Map<UUID, String>> set = new LinkedHashSet<Map<UUID,String>>();
    set.add(map);

    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(set));
}
```

producing the output

```
["java.util.LinkedHashSet",[{"@class":"java.util.HashMap","00000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000002":"value1"}]]
```

I'm trying to get Jackson printing the fully qualified java class for the UUID and the String objects I have inside the Map.